# About NP-completeness and reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Probably this is a basic question but I'm not sure how to finish this proof. I have a problem $X$ and I want to prove that it is possible to reduce $X$ to another problem $Y$. I know that $Y$ is NP-complete and that $Y$ can be reduced to $X$. Can I just conclude that $X$ is also NP-complete and thus $X$ can be reduced to $Y$? Is it necessary to show that $X$ is in NP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot conclude that.

Knowing that $Y$ is NP-complete and reduces to $X$ is only enough to conclude that $X$ is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness#Definition).

To show that $X$ can be reduced to $Y$ you will have to either prove that $X\in NP$, or show a reduction directly (don't do this, it is probably harder than just solving $X$ itself).